# Connect Raspberry Pi2 to Windows 10 Shared folder

Tags: raspbian, samba

I have already shared a folder inside my Windows 10 computer in this address `192.168.1.179/Toshiba`. And I would like to connect my `Raspberry pi 2` to that folder so I can access all my files inside my `Raspberry` . The IP Address of my `Raspberry Pi 2` is `192.168.1.132`.

I don't need a password to connect with `Windows shared folder`.

I tried to use this command inside `Raspberry Pi 2`:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.179/Toshiba mount-point
```

I already have a folder called `mount-point` inside my `Raspberry Pi 2`.

**Error**

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I can access to that folder if I use `smbclient`, I just write

```
smbclient //192.168.1.179/Toshiba
```

And the terminal shows me

```
Enter ismael's password:
Domain=[SALÓN] OS=[Windows 10 Pro 10240] Server=[Windows 10 Pro 6.3]
smb: \>
```

If I write `dir` or `ls` the prompt says me :

```
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to specify the option
-o username=your_username on windows

I believe it will prompt you for a password or you can specify it with the password=your_password

smclient is looking at the share which anyone can do but accessing the files on the share is limited to people who have an account.

Comment: Updated information.